# Return current page with an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application where the business layer throws an exception in case of errors. For example when someone tries to register with an email adress that is already registered in our database. For specific exceptions, I want to re-render the current view (with the data filled in by the user), and show an error message on top of the page.

Instead of adding try/catch statements to all controller actions, I've created a class that is derived from HandleErrorAttribute, to catch all exceptions on a central place. In this class, I render the current view by returning a new ViewResult, and copying the ViewData:

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
  public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
  {
     filterContext.Result = ShowErrorMessage("Error occured", filterContext);
     filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

     base.OnException(filterContext);
  }

  private static ActionResult ShowErrorMessage(string message, ExceptionContext filterContext)
  {
     filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = message;
     return new ViewResult { ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData };
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the ViewData doesn't contain the complete model. For example, fields that are marked as disabled, are not posted back to the controller. So when I render the view again, some fields will be empty.

Am I missing something here? Or should I go in a different direction to show the current page again, with an error message?

Comment: Why not use simply `ModelState.AddModelError` and `Html.ValidationSummary` ?

Comment: Where are you calling `ShowErrorMessage` ,method ?

Comment: @Shyju I've updated the code with a simplified version of my class.

Comment: If the email is already being used, why do you handle it in exception? Exceptions should not be used for control flow

Comment: @GGO Is it possible to call ModelState from your business layer?

Comment: @Shyju At first we started out by returning error codes back to the controller, but that gave a lot of overhead, and complicated our controllers. So then we decided to use exceptions instead.

Comment: @Joost yes, see the GTown-Code's answer, it's the best way to do this. He was quicker than me to answer but that's how i will have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go in a different direction for handling these kind of situations.  MVC already provides a much easier way to display errors to the user via the ModelState.

I'm going to provide an example which is 100% an assumption of what you might have.. since zero code was provided in the question as to how your controller and view currently look.

For example:

In your controller (I assume you're talking about the Create ActionResult).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Property1, Property2, Property3, EmailAddress")] Object myObject)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(db.TableName.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(myObject.EmailAddress, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EmailAddress", "This Email Already Exists!");
            return View(myObject);
        }

        /* otherwise continue */
    }
}
```

Then you said that you want to display that error message at the top of the view.

So, in your view you have a line that looks like this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Typically, the first parameter is always `true` because by default you have lines like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

that reside under their corresponding text boxes.  So, if you want to display errors at the top of the page, make sure that the `ValidationSummary` line is at the top of your form, and change `true` to `false`.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi GTown-Coder, thanks for your example! Based on the different answers I see exceptions are definitely not the way to go. What do you recommend when there are like 5 different errors for a typical action, that are returned from different classes in the business layer? Pass an enum with error codes back to the controller?

Comment: Can you give me an example? Based on that I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: For the registration example I gave, there can be 3 situations: the email address might already exist, the email address might be black listed, or the user is registered without errors. In some cases, these errors can come from different classes in the business layer. So what approach would you suggest for this?

Comment: @Joost why can't you just add another `if` statement?

Comment: I'm not talking about the if statement. Let's say the control flow in the application is like this: Controller -> Service -> DataAccessLayer. What is the recommended way to pass errors from the DAL back to the controller? Throw an exception, or pass an enum down the line to the controller?

Comment: You could use [data annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6) for model validations.  You can also build custom ones just like Shyju did below.  This way you don't include `if` statements in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

**You should not be using Exceptions for control flow**! That is a bad practice.

For your specific use case,(when someone tries to register with an email which was already registered), You can create a custom validation attribute and use the Model validation framework available in MVC.

```
public class UniqueEmail : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return $"This email ({name}) is already registered";
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object objValue,ValidationContext context)
    {
        var email = objValue as string;

        int userId= Int32.MinValue;
        var idProperty = context.ObjectType.GetProperty("Id");
        if (idProperty != null)
        {
            var idValue = idProperty.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (idValue != null)
            {
                userId = (int) idValue;
            }
        }

        var userRepository = new UserRepository();

        var e = userRepository.GetUser(email);

        if (e!=null && userId!=e.Id)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(email));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Here in this validation attribute, i read the value of the property on which this attribute is applied (in your case, it will be email), query the database to see whether we have a record exist with that email and if yes, we will compare the Id property value of that user record is different than the current view model's Id property value (this is to handle editing of the user record).

In the above code, I am using `UserRepository` which has a `GetUser` method to check whether we already have a record with this email in the system. Just update that part with however you want to check it with your data access code.

Now all you have to do is, decorate your view model with this attribute

```
public class  CreateUserVm
{
   public int Id { set;get;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
   [UniqueEmail]
   public string Email { set;get;}

   public string Name { set;get; }
}
```

And in your HttpPost action method, simply check `ModelState` is valid before saving data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserVm model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid) 
   {
      // all good. Save
      return RedirectToAction("Index");     
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

When model validation fails, it will render the validation errors in your view, assuming you have the validation helpers in your view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", true)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

   @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.Id)
   <input type="submit"  />
}
```